# DOMPDF: Why is CSS chart not rendering properly to PDF while it is showing correctly in browser

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, dompdf

I am trying to generate pdf using dompdf. My HTML/CSS working fine in browser and also it is generating pdf. If I load the html site up itself, the CSS is all correct. But when I convert from the code to PDF file, it outputs wrong. It is not generating chart correctly in pdf. Please help what is going wrong here.

Here is my HTML/CSS file link so that you can review if anything is wrong.

http://codepen.io/ankitedrubric/pen/rrPvvo

and here is my PHP function to save pdf file.
Also i have enable def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);

```
    function generatepdf($id = FALSE, $attachment = FALSE) {
    try{
        $filename = "pdf_name1";
        $html = '';
        $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
        $this->load->library('parser');
        $data = array('hello1' => 'Hello Mars!!', 'hello2' => 'Hello Jupiter!!');
        $parse_data = '';
        $html = $this->parser->parse('filepath_of_html_page', $data);
        pdf_create($html, $filename, TRUE, $attachment);
        }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because DOMPDF is not a browser and does not use a browser. It's an entirely different CSS implementation.

Comment: Agree with above statement. If you want an advanced rendering engine you should use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: What actually i am trying that when i go to the page link it creates the chart in browser and also save that chart in a pdf file at the same time. but chart is not correctly displaying in pdf file. Is anything wrong with css?